# Count black pixels in coordinate area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following question:

I have a binary image containing only black and white pixels. How do I count the number of black pixels in a certain area of the image?

For example, I want know what is the amount of black pixels in this coordinates of image area:

[175,145],[229,145],[175,221],[229,221] = Top L&R and Lower L&R coordinates

Any idea how I can make this, please... :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By looping through rows, and then each pixel in that row (like one would a spreadsheet), you could test each pixel and add that to a tally.
There are many functions that work with images in PHP. One that I have used for similar purposes is [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php). You can test each pixel directly for it's RGB value using [imagecolorat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php).

**Pseudo Code**

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('/path/to/image.jpg'); //replace with your image type
$totalBlack = 0;
$area = array( //for your area to evaluate
    array(175, 145), 
    array(229, 145), 
    array(175, 221), 
    array(229, 221)
);
for ($y = $area[0][1]; $y < $area[2][1]; $y++ ) {
    for($x = $area[0][0]; $x < $area[3][0]; $x++ ) {
        $value = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        if ($value == /*test for black*/) {
            $totalBlack++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Using ImageMagick**
You could crop the image to the supplied x,y values and then use [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)'s compare function to compare that whole section to a plain white image.

Comment: Hi friend! Thanks for help! How I make /*test for black*/?

Comment: I'd begin by doing this for an image that is completely black. Then `var_dump` a couple of pixels to see what it returns. Do the same for a white image. Then do an `if` statement that compare $value to what you have discovered is the returned value for black.

Comment: I made a few errors in typing out my code that would be confusing. I've corrected them now. Namely the line that starts as `for($x = $area[0][0]`

Comment: @gelopes my testing shows that a (perfect) black pixel in a jpeg would result in a `0` value. Your testing may vary so make sure it matches your images, not mine.